# Cannot find js file of SignalR in ASP.NET 5

Tags: signalr, signalr.client, asp.net5

I'm making a small web application with ASP.NET 5 which implements SignalR. I've added SignalR nuget, everything works fine, but I cannot find js file of SignalR.

Here is my project images:

[image]

[image]

Am I missing any thing ?

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR 2.* doesn't work very well with ASP.NET core due to it using OWIN. I had it working at some point with V2 but it was just not well integrated with how ASP.NET core is now coded (split up)

If you are using RC1, I suggest using from
[ASP.NET Core "master" branch feed](https://web.archive.org/web/20160719095904/http://myget.org:80/gallery/aspnetmaster) or if you are using RC2 try the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server : 0.1.0-rc2-* package from the aspnetcirelease [feed](http://:%20https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcirelease/api/v3/index.json)

Comment: So what the lastest version of ASP.NET do you think I should use for coding SignalR ?

Comment: SignalR 3.0 would the version you want to look for in RC1: Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server : v3.0.0-rc1-final